# Converting from parts of a circle to polar coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

I have the area defined by

> $$A = \sqrt{x/4-(x/2)^2} < y < \sqrt{1-x^2)} \text{ and }0 < x < 1$$

and I'm supposed to find the integral of the function bound by these limits;

> $$I = \int_0^1\int_{\sqrt{x/4-(x/2)^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}f(x,y)\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}x$$

So I think it would be better to convert these to polar coordinates;

> $$I = \int_0^1\left(\int_0^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}f(x,y)\mathrm{d}y-\int_0^{\sqrt{x/4-(x/2)^2}}f(x,y)\mathrm{d}y\right)\mathrm{d}x\\
> I = \int_0^1\left(\int_0^{\tau/4}g(r,\theta)\mathrm{d}\theta-\int_?^?g(r,\theta)\mathrm{d}\theta\right)r\mathrm{d}r$$

But I'm not really sure how to proceed from here. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you have to do an integral or do you just have to find the area?

Comment: If you convert $f(x,y)$ to $f(r,\theta)$, you'd get the double integral of $\sqrt{1-r^2} r dr d\theta$, which is easy to compute given reasonable bounds. Then convert the bounds to polar and keep it as one double integral.

Comment: @JohnDouma 
 
I'll have to do the integral because the function is $f(x,y)=\sqrt{1−(x2+y2)}$
, so the area of the surface wouldn't really help me solve that...

Comment: @MatthewPereira The bounds are my problem.

Comment: @bob.sacamento gives the upper bound for $r$, and the lower bound should be $0$. Also, note that this function should have a period of $\pi$, so be careful with the bounds on $\theta$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\displaystyle y^2 = \frac{x}{4}-\frac{x^2}{4}$

so

$\displaystyle 4r^2 \sin^2\theta = r\cos\theta-r^2\cos^2\theta$

and

$\displaystyle 4r = \cos\theta+3r\cos^2\theta$

You could try solving this for $r$:  $\displaystyle r=\frac{\cos\theta}{4-3\cos^2\theta}$, then let $r$ be your inner integral and integrate over $r$ from zero to that limit.  You might also try to solve for $\cos\theta$, let your inner integral be over $\theta$ from 0 to that limit, but that is looking kind of hairy to me.  Unless $f(x,y)$ has some particularly nice form, I don't see any clean way to do this.

EDIT: Just saw the comments.  Matthew Pereira has the right idea.

Comment: Wouldn't $x/4 - x^2/4 < y^2 < 1-x^2 \implies x/4 < y^2+x^2 < 1 \implies \frac{r}{4}\cos(\theta) < r^2 < 1$, and then I could split it into $0 < r^2 < 1$ and $0 < r^2 < \frac{r}{4}\cos(\theta)$ which would imply $\int_{\frac{r}{4}\cos(\theta)}^1 = \int_0^1-\int_0^{\frac{1}{4}\cos(\theta)}$ ?

Comment: @Frank Vel  The way I see it $x/4-x^2/4<y^2<1-x^2 \implies x/4+3x^2/4<y^2+x^2<1$